# Conflict with simulation cron

Tags: angularjs, cordova, time, intervals, ionic-framework

Community, I have the following problem. I am running an action every certain stretch of time, for example, 1 minute. The function, if the device is locked continues to run normally but there comes a time (about 5 minutes) fails, no error or any type of log to run, to keep track of the function check my log server as I check my webservice and receives more requests. I am occupying the interval function and as I said, it works well about 5 minutes and then with nothing to stop running calls.

```
setInterval(function(){update()}, 10000);
```

If anyone knows how to solve or a better way to simulate a cron on a device agradeceria.

Thanks!

Comment: @isherwood Ok, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the js runtime was unloaded from the device browser for your page (since the user is not looking at it and the device wants to save on battery), that is why it stops working, I don't think it is possible to overcome this completely

you could somewhat fake it by saving last run time in localStorage and running your code with [windows.onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onfocus) to determine what changes need to be made (did not test if it actually works tho I see no reason for it not to work)

Comment: Save last run time? A What do you mean by that?

Comment: since your job runs every x seconds, you need to be able to tell if you need to run the update or not when the event fires (I assume you don't want to run it too often), this event will fire every time user focuses your app so you need to take it into account

Comment: the truth is that if I need to run, I have a function that query to a webservice if a person has a new data into a career, if so, sending a notice. The notification works fine as I said, to 5 minutes or so of execution. As you say, the ability to know whether it is necessary or not, perform the function longer. The strange thing is that it stops working ...

Comment: that is what I tried to explain in the first paragraph of my answer, the fact that browsers try to optimize what the cpu runs, and running js in a browser on a locked phone/tablet or even a background tab seem unnecessary, maybe try to experiment with something as simple as: `setInterval(function(){console.log(new Date)}, 1000)` and see when it stops/restarts, though I also see no reason for your code to be running since the user will not see the outcome anyway, hope this helps

Comment: I understand all your help, but I is difficult to detect when the interval stops working

Comment: you wont be able to detect it in your code (since none of it will be running anymore), though I would not worry about it since user is not looking at your page anyway and when they come back the interval should continue (if it does not you can use onfocus to make sure it does)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot to tell you that every time I find something new in my webservice, sent a push notification. There is the problem and I think I'll have to handle database.

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode, I solve my problem, should you ever need it.